# Помогите решить задачку в области работы с БД в РНР

Tags: php, mysql

Сначала нужно было вывести данные о пользователях из базы в таблицу, после - влепить напротив каждого пользователя кнопку (ссылку) "удалить", нажимая которую удаляется запись из БД. Таблицу с кнопкой построил. Теперь пытаюсь реализовать механизм удаления записи из таблицы в БД.

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['delete_id'])) {
  $id=$_GET['delete_id'];
  $queryUserDel= "DELETE FROM $table WHERE id=$id;"
  $mysqlqueryUserDel = mysqli_query($link, $queryUserDel); 

}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>DB</title>
    <style>
        table, tr, th, td {
            border: 1px solid green;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>age</th>
            <th>salary</th>
        </tr>
<?php

    $host = 'localhost';
    $user = 'root';
    $pass = '123QWErty';
    $db_name ='test_db' ;
    $table = '`people`';

    $link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db_name) or die (mysqli_error($link));
    mysqli_set_charset($connect, 'utf8');

    $query = " SELECT * FROM $table";

    $mysqlquery = mysqli_query($link, $query);



    while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($mysqlquery, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {


    echo "<tr><td>{$result['id']}</td><td>{$result['name']}</td><td>{$result['age']}</td><td>{$result['salary']}</td><td><a href=\"?delete_id={$result['id']}\">Удалить</a></td></tr>";

    } 

    ?>
        </table>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Вы забыли озвучить, в чём всё-таки проблема, и чем вам помочь

Comment: Код, который перед html - то, с помощью чего я пытаюсь удалить запись из БД. Вот он не работает.

Comment: у вас на момент вызова кода удаления переменная `$table` не определена. зы: для удаления обычно используют POST запросы, а не GET

Comment: впрочем, как и `$link`

Comment: Я просто следовал условиям задачи. У меня мелькнула мысль, что может быть объявить всё то, что объявлено ниже, снова. Сейчас буду пробовать, спасибо.

Comment: а передача параметра `100 or 1=1` удалит вам вообще все строки

Answer (score 0):

Вы пытаетесь выполнить запрос на удаление до того, как открываете соединение с базой данных. Блок

```
$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '123QWErty';
$db_name ='test_db' ;
$table = '`people`';

$link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db_name) or die(mysqli_error($link));
mysqli_set_charset($link, 'utf8');
```

Необходимо вынести в начало скрипта.

Comment: Попробовал перенести код ниже </table>, не идёт всё равно:

Comment: Если вы переносите код ниже table, то он выполняется после того, как отрисуется таблица. То есть, запись удаляется, но вы видите её наличие в старых данных.

Comment: Да у меня вообще ничего не удаляется :)

Comment: Напишите после строки $mysqlqueryUserDel код `var_export($queryUserDel); var_export($mysqlqueryUserDel);` и пришлите результат

Comment: У меня наверное более примитивные проблемы в коде: HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: Ну да) `$queryUserDel= "DELETE FROM $table WHERE id=$id;"` забыли ";" в конце строки.